# Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource, dataview

I tried bind a label from result SqlDataSource.But I get this error

> Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1"  FilterExpression="DeviceID='{0}'"   
   runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConn %>" 
   SelectCommand="SELECT devcocom_admin.SensorDataPackage.a_TankLevel1, 
    devcocom_admin.SensorDataPackage.a_TankLevel2,devcocom_admin.DeviceID bla bla 
    bla Where bla bla ">

         <FilterParameters>


       <asp:ControlParameter Name="DeviceID" ControlID="lblDeviceIDText" 
        PropertyName="Text" />
       </FilterParameters>

         </asp:SqlDataSource>


 private void GetData()
    {
        DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        DataRowView drv =dv[0];

        lblTank1.Text = drv["a_TankLevel1"].ToString();
        lblTank2.Text = drv["a_TankLevel2"].ToString();
    }  


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      lblDeviceIDText.Text = this.m_Dealer.DeviceID.ToString();

       // e.g lblDeviceIDText.Text=12345 can display on page 

      GetData();           
   }
```

I get error at this line

> DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
>
> Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32

Comment: `DeviceID` is apparently an integer, and you're trying to compare it to a string. Don't do that?

Comment: In case you didn't get the memo, using SQL Data Sources in ASP.NET webforms is, and never was a good idea. You have data access code in your view!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `DbType="Int32"` to the `ControlParameter`. Here is the [property link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.dbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and the [enum link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Mehmet, I'm guess that the value of that control then is not integral.

Comment: @Mehmet, not the data type of the table, the value of the control. The control you're grabbing the parameter value from.

Comment: I can bind a gridview from this sqldatasource.But I can not bind a label !

Comment: @Mehmet, what's the text of the label? Again, it must not be integral.

Comment: It was like that   <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblDeviceIDText" runat="server" Text="lblDeviceIDText" Font-Bold="true">
    </dx:ASPxLabel>   I changed it <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblDeviceIDText" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="true">
    </dx:ASPxLabel>   but result is wrong ! Filter is not working